In PowerBI I can't Load Excel file
I am trying to load data to Power BI and I get the below massage
"failed to save modifications to the server. error returned: 'the provider 'microsoft.powerbi.oledb' is not registered. the following system error occurred: class not registered '."

I tried to enter data manual from Enter data and I got the same error. Your help please.


pls check if this is helpful
enter link description here
what's more, pls try to turn on parallel loading of tables.

